# How to create dynamic models with attributes on form submit

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some tables which are nothing but my company services(WAPT, MAPT, NAPT etc). these services are predefined but now team want to add new services with different attributes. They can able to add multiple service table with different columns. Is this possible.

I tried active_dynamic but it's about adding attributes to existing table but i need multiple tables here with dynamic attributes.

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail about the structure of your application/models? Ideally you would include some code samples. Based on your question though, it seems like you have a Service model which is expected to store the name of a service?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can create models for the service you know and create a generic model for the services you don't know about